# Convert jquery to javascript with socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

How can I convert jquery code into pure javascript.

I am using the socket.io library.

```
var socket = io("localhost:3000");
$('form').submit(function () {
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
});
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
});
```

Comment: I posted a solution below, but for as something as simple as converting code from jquery to javascript, you should really just look it up. You should pose questions that you can't figure out. Nothing from your questions says "I can't figure x out, please help me, this is what I tried and this is the problem I'm running in to." It comes off as lazy and thats why people are going to downvote the question.

Comment: okay i will try to do that next time it is just that i am not very good at jquery and i ahve seen other questions like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this should work: (untested)

```
var socket = io("localhost:3000"),
    form = document.querySelector("form"),
    m = document.querySelector("#m"),
    messages = document.querySelector("#messages");
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit("chat message", m.value);
    m.value = "";
});
socket.on("chat message", function(msg){
    var _li = document.createElement("li");
    _li.innerHTML = msg;
    messages.appendChild(_li);
});
```

Comment: thankyou so much i just tested the code and it worked

Comment: yeah no problem, see my comment to your question above. It will save you some downvotes in the future :)